# Preventing height of a block element from pushing other block elements without absolute positioning?

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/arandomcodepenuser/pen/NWjYGwo

Ok, so I have this top navbar, and the problem is that I can't change the html only the styling, because I am using a Wordpress plugin, and this navbar has block elements on the navbar, and there's one of them that has a dropdown within the element and not below, and I can't use javascript to change this, I am wondering if it's possible for the dropdown embedded within the li element to push down the other elements on the navbar when it appears on hover.

Here's the html:

```
<div>
   <ul class="top-bar__menu">
      <li id="menu-item-265276" class=""><a href=""><span>Find Us</span></a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-280208" class="">
         <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-268209" class=""><a href=""><span>About Us</span></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-265276" class=""><a href=""><span>Find Us</span></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-280209" class=""><a href="" aria-current="page"><span>Our Team</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the css styling for the dropdown menu:

```
.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li {
  clear:both;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Your current codepen doesn’t appear to show any dropdown. Plus, a proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ inside your question, not just dumped onto some external platform.

Comment: the dropdown is the submenu, I didn't implement it the submenu, because the problem occurs on hover.

Comment: Your pen shows it all the time, and there is no different formatting for any hover state. And there isn’t even any following content, that you are talking about. You need to provide a better [mre] to begin with here, something that actually shows your issue.

Comment: The problem is shown by the fact that the other navbar item is not properly aligned.